# Cakephp 3 Custom Query Error

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

Im trying to follow an example from the manual on cakephp 3;

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods

```
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ArticlesTable extends Table
{

    public function findOwnedBy(Query $query, array $options)
    {
        $user = $options['user'];
        return $query->where(['author_id' => $user->id]);
    }

}

// In a controller or table method.
$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$query = $articles->find('ownedBy', ['user' => $userEntity]);
```

I keep getting the same error;

> Trying to get property of non-object
>   [APP/Model\Table\BookmarksTable.php, line 108]
>
> Code Context
>       {
>           $user = $options['user'];

```
    return $query->where(['user_id' => $user->id]);
```

It points to the line;

> $user = $options['user'];

Whats wrong with this line?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm was passing in the wrong value to the method.